# Custom serialization with Javassist-generated proxy class

Tags: proxy-classes, javassist

I have a proxy class generated by Javassist's `ProxyFactory` for a serializable class. I need to send an instance of the target class represented by the proxy class over RMI, but the remote client does not have the proxy class code so that I can only send its target instance. This would mean only the target instance should be serialized without the proxy class code. The proxy class does not have any state, except for a reference to its target.

Is this possible with `ProxyFactory`?

Comment: Doesn't intercepting __writeReplace__ method in the proxy `class` in order only serialize the inner field solve your problem?

Comment: @pabrantes The target class does not define writeReplace. There are so many classes to stub, so it's not feasible to define one in each class.